# How to update a camera position in mapview class

Tags: dart, flutter

Mapview is a class where I will show user vehicle location, I have a scenario in which I have to show a live tracking of that vehicle to get that I have to update the camera position. How can I get that?

```
mapView.show(
    new MapOptions(
      mapViewType: MapViewType.normal,
      initialCameraPosition: new CameraPosition(new Location(lattitude,longitude), 17.0),
      showUserLocation: true,
      showCompassButton: true,
      showMyLocationButton: true,
      title:_vehicleNumbers[0].toString(),
    ),
    toolbarActions: [
      ToolbarAction('Close',1),
    ]   
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to monitor the location of the user's device somehow. On the dart pub there is a nice location package... [Flutter Location Package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location)

This provides a callback on location update. You then need to call the `setCameraPosition` function on the mapView object to update the view:

```
var location = new Location();
location.onLocationChanged.listen((Map<String,double> currentLocation) {
 var latitude = currentLocation["latitude"];
 var longitude = currentLocation["longitude"];
 mapView.setCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(new Location(lattitude,longitude), 17.0));
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think no need to app location package again, I got that by the line mapView.setCameraPosition(); its updated when i have new long and lat values.

Comment: @HarshaVardhan Great, glad you got it to work, please remember to mark as the answer if this solved your problem.